# Node.js Twilio make calls using REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to make call from the Twilio REST API but I am getting an error, looks like I missed something, any help will appreciate:

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxx/Calls',
  headers: 
   { 
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
  formData: 
   { To: '+919200070974',
     From: '14245060471',
     Url: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Response>\n    <Say voice="woman">This is me....</Say>\n</Response>'} };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Now I set url parameters but its showing invalid

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse>
    <RestException>
        <Code>21205</Code>
        <Message>Url is not a valid url: &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">This is me....</Say>
</Response></Message>
        <MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21205</MoreInfo>
        <Status>400</Status>
    </RestException>
</TwilioResponse>
```

I am not getting where I have to set URL parameter, I didn't find in the documentation clearly what I have to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you need to do in this case, is send to Twilio a URL. When the call connects, Twilio will then make a request to that URL to get the TwiML response.

[From the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#url-parameter):

> When you initiate a call through the REST API, Twilio makes a synchronous HTTP request to the URL found in the value of the 'Url' POST parameter, in order to retrieve TwiML for handling the call. This request is identical to the request Twilio sends when receiving a phone call to one of your Twilio numbers. URLs must contain a valid hostname (underscores are not permitted).

So, your `formData` here should be:

```
formData: {
  To: '+919200070974',
  From: '14245060471',
  Url: 'https://example.com/twiml'
}
```

And the URL at `https://example.com/twiml` should respond with the TwiML you defined originally.

Answer (score 1):

[twilio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) has an npm library already.

you can follow their [Node.js Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node)

```
// Twilio Credentials
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';

// require the Twilio module and create a REST client
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
  .create({
    to: '+15558675310',
    from: '+15017122661',
    body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
  })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Comment: I dont want to use SDK/Libraries , i am using rest api

Comment: Any reason to not use official library.

Comment: I have implemented all other twiio apis(send/get sms, get voice calls) with rest , so only for this i dont want to add library

Comment: Solved Thanks guys ,Its require proper xml file url with hostname, now its working